# webview.loadUrl("about:blank") issue

Tags: android, webview

In my application I have a webview in which initially I load any website, say www.google.com.
Later on a button click I want to clear this webview, for which I do

```
webview.loadUrl("about:blank");
```

But doing this does not clear my webview, it continues to display google.com

I tried to re initialize the webview as

```
webview = new WebView(this);
webview.loadUrl("about:blank");
```

I also tried

```
webview.clearHistory();
webview.loadUrl("about:blank");
```

But I got the same results, the webview displays google.com
How can I clear the webview?
Please suggest.
Thank You.

**Edit:**
On the other hand, before loading google.com if I do

```
webview.loadUrl("about:blank");
```

it loads a blank webpage.

Answer (score 9):

use `webView.clearView();` before loading the new URL.

also use 
There are a couple of things you can do to clear the webview depending exactly what you want to do:

```
webView.clearCache(true);

webView.clearHistory();

webView.destroy();
```

Comment: @Zeba hey this is used for u then upvote on my question so any1 can also use this ans.

Comment: later on I faced issues with this answer... my web view would blank out but after a few seconds google would load again.. also if I touch the webview then google page would load again.. So finally I could not use this solution.

Comment: @Zeba hey can u just post your file in stackoverflow so i can check it and try to check whats exactly your problem

Comment: UPDATE: `webView.clearView();` is now deprecated in API level 18. Use `WebView.loadUrl("about:blank")` to reliably reset the view state and release page resources (including any running JavaScript). See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#clearView()

Answer (score 5):

just to update, method clearView() was deprecated in API level 18.
 
Use WebView.loadUrl("about:blank") to reliably reset the view state and release page resources (including any running JavaScript).

Comment: Indeed. The problem is that, even if you load 'about:blank' and then reset the history, the blank page remains in the history. If only there were a (still) a working clearView() function that just did whatever was necessary!

Answer (score 3):

try the following : `webView.loadData("");`

Comment: This is the way I use to load an empty page and it perfectly works.